# Sorting Data without messing formulas dependencies - Gantt chart

Tags: excel, vba

I´ve created a simple VBA code that sorts the column "J" below (see image) by the status of the task. However, the problem i´m facing is that some of the tasks are dependent of the finish date of the previous one, which then defines the Gantt chart.

By sorting each line, the formulas dependencies get messed up because they keep referencing the same cell to define the start date, and not the new "sorted" position.

Any idea how I solve this problem?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: I know you might want something more advanced, but tag the rows off the table with row number or something , before sorting , so you have a record of the order before the sort . Vice versa as necc. It's a generic answer to how I would approach the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution is to use the `INDIRECT()` worksheet function. To use your example, instead of using the formula `=M43+1` you can use `=INDIRECT("M43")+1`. However, in this state the formula is as good (or bad) as hard-coded and you won't be able to autofill the whole column. To make it more dynamic you change it to `=INDIRECT("M"&ROW())+1`.

Another approach is to use the `OFFSET()` worksheet function. In this case you can use `=OFFSET(K44,0,2)`. Hope this works for you.